# AJAX with PHP on Web - Security

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

On some of my web I write with `JS`/`HTML`/`CSS` because is dynamic. 
But when I working with DB I must call `Ajax` from `JS` to working with it. I use POST in `Ajax`, but how secure is it?

Can someone use my URL with `PHP` (like www.smt.com/updateDB.php) to edit my DB?

Because when I use it from `JS` without password and name, so anyone can use it. And if you have Name of DB, Password and Name of User in POST `Ajax`, then anynone can see it.

Is there any way to secure it in `PHP`? Like it only update DB when its send from my Hosting IP address?

Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

instead of using ip adddresses you need a login system and session controller in php. so in php part for every ajax request you can esily check if user logged in or have rights to run db functions

Comment: Nice idea, but i need that Ajax will be able to do anything with DB, like download list of user, not only logged user. But user is able to edit JS. So how secure this?